# Storybook's migration

Tags: javascript, storybook

I want to migrate Storybook from `5.0.11` to `5.2.0` but after changing the version in `package.json` I got:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat' in '/home/twaszczyk/workspaces/ui-elements/node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/utils.js 9:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/index.js
 @ ./config/.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./config/.storybook/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat' in '/home/twaszczyk/workspaces/ui-elements/node_modules/@storybook/theming/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger/dist/index.js 3:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/ensure.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/index.js
 @ ./config/.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./config/.storybook/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.for-each' in '/home/twaszczyk/workspaces/ui-elements/node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/index.js 3:0-44
 @ ./config/.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./config/.storybook/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/convert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.index-of' in '/home/twaszczyk/workspaces/ui-elements/node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/convert.js 5:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/index.js
 @ ./config/.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./config/.storybook/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true
```

I was looking for also in migration guide but nothing found what I should to do to finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the solution (hope this help):

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  }
}
```

Migrated dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/addon-centered": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/addon-info": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/addon-storysource": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/components": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/react": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/source-loader": "^5.2.0",
"@storybook/theming": "^5.2.0",
```

It was needed also to move from `babel-loader` to `ts-loader`.